# How to change product zero prices to text in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I need to change all product zero prices to custom text - free and enable/disable this function from admin?

Comment: Do you want to text instead of 0 in frontend PDP?

Comment: Yes, i want to show them in frontend in all pages where is product.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite big. But you can go with following way:

For listing and PDP:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox">
        <plugin name="change_text_for_free_product" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Pricing\Render\PriceBox" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface;

class PriceBox
{
    public function aroundRenderAmount(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        AmountInterface $amount,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if ($subject->getPrice()->getValue() <= 0) {
            return 'Free';
        }

        return $proceed($amount, $arguments);
    }
}
```

For Minicart overwrite following template and add logic:

> vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml

For checkout sidebar:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="weee_row_incl_tax" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="weee_row_excl_tax" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/checkout/summary/item/price/row_excl_tax</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now copy **vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/item/price** two template and added your logic here.

Comment: What is the above method, is it preference? or core rewrite @Sohel Rana Thank you.

Comment: @zus that is the plugin.

Comment: may i know the plugin details?